# Randomize game objects actions, so they won't happen at the same time

Tags: unity-game-engine, fsm

I wrote a script that change states for my NPCs. I run a function that return either true or false. if it is true, the NPC change state.

All is fine, except that I see more than one NPC acting exactly at the same time, which look horrible. Feels like they are a military squadron, perfectly synced.

I use a random value to check if the function should return true or false...but I was expecting to see different results for each NPC, since the random value is in place

```
class void NPCState()
{

    private System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
    private string state;    

    Void Start()
    {
        state = "state1";
        StartCoroutine("RunAction");
    }

    IEnumerator RunAction()
    {
        ...do stuff every N cycles
        switch (state)
        {  
            case "state1":
                ... go to state 1                
                break;
            case "state2":
                ... go to state 2
                break;
        }
    }  

    void State1()
    {
        ... execute certain tasks
        if (ChangeActionType)
        {
             ...change to a different action type
             state = state2;
        }
    }

    void State2()
    {
        ... execute certain tasks
        ... then go back to previous task
        state = state1;
    }

    private bool ChangeActionType()
    {
        if (rnd.next(100) > 50)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I did simplify the code to show the part where the state change; and this is basically happening at the same exact time for multiple NPC.

How can I create enough variety in a script, so each NPC may update at random time? I just want to avoid that they will all act like synchro swimmers :)

Comment: add a small random delay (=wait for a few frames)? add a 2nd or even 3rd animation variant? also, do you know how to shuffle a deck of cards? you could try to apply somethign similar instead of just random, this way you have a bit more influence over the randomness.

Comment: I see; how would you add more delay? If I make another coroutine that wait a certain amount of time, would that be enough to not have a lot of NPC to do the action at the same time? BTW the issue is not shuffling animations, I do that already, but if all NPC are idle, and then you see half of them starting to do something at the same time, it looks horrible, even if they perform a different action :)

Comment: I was wondering why do you prefer System.Random to UnityEngine.Random? Is there any difference?

Comment: @NikaKasradze : yes. System.Random return integers, and the range can be specified in integers; while Unity allow ranges only with floats. This has a weight to a certain extent, if you use mainly integers, since a float is more expensive as datatype, compared to an integer. Also you save the hassle to cast from float to int.

Comment: @newbiez do you need to set all at once? you could only set 10%, then 3 fames later another 10%. in total thats 30frames or half a second. sure you will notice a very tiny delay until the last unit starts doing stuff, but youll also have the animations vary in time. ofc the numbers are only suggestions, i have no clue how it would look, it sure will need tweaking, but as programmer you probably have an aversion for constants anyway ^^ also if you go down this road, make sure you dont have the 10% "in-order" or it will look weird again. shuffle the array in advance.

Comment: @nebiez no, UnityEngine.Random.Range(int, int) gives you integers, only if you pass it float you get a float back.

Comment: @yes: The API state clearly that you can only pass floats : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: seems the documentation is incomplete on this. Random.Range has 2 overloads, if you pass int you get int back, if you pass float you get float back.

Comment: No, I do not need to set them all at once, but picture the scenario: NPC do things, go to sleep, wake up at different times; they should operate differently and independently from each other. I do not understand how can you manipulate the events by frames; update happens every frame; if you run a coroutine, it happens at certain point, but they are still part of a game cycle, so unless you state clearly in a different script, a different timing; they will all follow the same update cycle, triggering at the same time when the conditions are satisfied. I can make different scripts...a waste IMO

Comment: Good to know; I read the docs before use something in the API, so I assume that they are updated and complete. I will gladly change from system.Random to UnityEngine.Random.

Comment: so your agents are completely autonomous and only act at the same time because the event is happening at this very time? then let each instance set their own random wait time in the coroutine? even if its called seconds, it takes a float, so set the wait time big enough to have a difference, but small enough to not have them stand around for eternities, a frame is roughly 0.016s http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

Comment: @newbiez you should also read intellisense for the overloads, not every overload is in the docs.

Comment: Yes, they behave following a FSM, as you may hint from the code example. They are totally independent; they react when certain parameters change, modifying their state and performing different animations accordingly. I did try with a coroutine, using WaitForSeconds; after all the whole FSM works on a coroutine, but the variance was too little. I have to play with numbers and see if I can find an acceptable wait, that does not carry over the next cycle, or the FSM updates will go off timing and the whole thing will fall apart :)

Comment: and a "have target but wait" state? sry, i admit i only read the text not the code :D

Comment: @yes, sure; I can use intellisense if I am typing it, but if I read the docs, I see the float in the signature, and move on :) To save time, I read docs first, find what I need and then implement it; otherwise I go blindly trying stuff, just because their name may sound similar to what I want. It may work, but is not exactly the best approach for me.

Comment: @newbiez yeah that sounds a lot like me ^^

Comment: @newbiez btw i only just read this article on gamestates a few days ago, maybe thats interesting for you aswell. ive not tried it yet, but it sounds like a quite nice concept to me. (ofc you dont need the draw part in unity) http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/brain-dead-simple-game-states-r4262

Comment: Nice article, although very simple :) This one goes more in details, if FSM for AI are your thing : http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/finite-state-machines-theory-and-implementation--gamedev-11867